# how do I fit my background image in between borders that I made in my website

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to fit an image in between borders that I put in for design in the website, I can't figure out a way to do it.

Here is my code for the body:

```
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-image: url("background.png");
background-image: url("background.png"), linear-gradient(180deg, #219DA5 0%, #18485F 25%, #18485F 75%, #219DA5 100%);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;height: 100vh;
overflow: hidden;
border-bottom: 40px solid #219DA5;
border-top: 40px solid #219DA5;}
```

I tried messing with background-positioning and size but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Can we have your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine except the bottom border cannot be seen because it's off the bottom of the viewport.

This is because of the default setting in browsers for the box-sizing property - the borders are outside the given height of the element so the whole thing is too tall to show.

If you change the box-sizing to border-box the borders will be included.

This is what we get now (obviously without your actual image as I don't have access to that, but the linear-gradient shows the extent of the background image between those two borders):

[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-image: url("background.png");
  background-image: url("background.png"), linear-gradient(180deg, #219DA5 0%, #18485F 25%, #18485F 75%, #219DA5 100%);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #219DA5;
  border-top: 40px solid #219DA5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```